# Jquery Mobile Autocomplete using JSONP

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jsonp

Anyone have a working example of a remote JSONP call (e.g. ws.geonames.com) with jquery mobile autocomplete?

I have found and can get working other combinations (jsonp remote without jqm, jqm local autocomplete, etc), but jqm autocomplete with jsonp remote calls is mangling the request (encoding the function code and sending it to localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
            $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
                var $ul = $( this ),
                    $input = $( data.input ),
                    value = $input.val(),
                    html = "";
                $ul.html( "" );
                if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                    $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: {
                            q: $input.val()
                        }
                    })
                    .then( function ( response ) {
                        $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                            html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                        });
                        $ul.html( html );
                        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                        $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```